# jQuery how to select div number x from a series of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a number of divs in a container like so:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to select divs 2 and 3 using jquery and assign a class to them. I know how to use .addClass, but I don't know how I select specific divs

Comment: [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/), [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

Comment: That's the one, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eq().

```
$('.container div:eq(1), .container div:eq(2)').addClass('red');
```

This will select item 2 and 3 and update their class in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [`.slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method:

```
$('.item').slice(1,3).addClass("CLASS");
```

Comment: In this case of using slice() and to select elements 2 & 3, it should be: `$('.item').slice(1,3)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('.item').slice(1,3)` to get a range like in already posted answer or alternatively, you could use as selectors [:lt](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) & [:gt](https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/):

```
$('.item:gt(0):lt(2)')
```

```js
$('.item:gt(0):lt(2)').css('color','red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method !
please see the below codes

html codes :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

javascript codes :

```
$('.item').slice(1,3).addClass('this');
```

Run jsfiddle! here "https://jsfiddle.net/gLeagw8s/"